# Which app has a notification sound with 3 descending notes?

Tags: windows, audio, notifications

Brand new Windows 7 box loaded with the usual dev tools -- VS2008, Firefox, Chatzilla, Thunderbird, emacs, Pidgin, Putty, iTunes, SharpReader.

Every couple of minutes, I get an audio notification consisting of three rising
notes, maybe a middle-C-G-F on a piano (I don't have a piano handy, and don't have
time to use GarageBand to try to figure it out).

Nothing in the notification bar is flashing when this happens.

The sound isn't in any of the Windows Sound control panel applets.  And it's not
in C:\Windows\Media, so it's most likely coming from a non-Microsoft app.

Any chance it's Pidgin when the status one of my contact's changes (which happens plenty frequently)?  Oh, look at this --- Tools/Mute Sounds.  Let's try that and see what happens...

Is this familiar to anyone?

Comment: Rising notes as in the text or descending notes as in the subject?

Comment: Ummm, both. I gather when someone becomes active the notes rise, and when he/she leaves they descend. A butt-ugly useless feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think I know exactly what it is. It's the sound Pidgin makes when it has activity. Go mute it :)

Edit: Looks like you found it too. Ninja'd

Comment: Found this answer by googling "windows 3 note sound". Damn that was annoying! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open the volume control window. It should list the last several applications to emit a sound. 
[image: Windows 7 Volume Mixer]

Comment: Yup, confirmed.